# Add header to any page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to create a bit of embeddable code that a user can drop into their website that will load some Javascript. If some conditions are met, I'd like to add a small header to the top of the site, pushing down the rest of the content. Is there a simple way to do this that'll work on most websites?

I understand how to load and execute the JS - I guess I'm just wondering what the HTML/CSS would look like on both my header, and what would need to be altered on the user's site.

Comment: a lot of sites have headers that need to be at the top because of their css; pushing it down would not work well.

Comment: your  app would have to find all the page's content that has a position:fixed; and move it down.  this could be incredibly messy

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a floating header on top of their websites as opposed to shifting their entire website down? I think that'd be significantly easier.

That way you could just smack a `div` anywhere like so:

```
<div id="header">Whatever content</div>

<style>
#header {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:280px;
    position: fixed;
}
</style>
```

Or you could remove the `position: fixed` if that's too annoying and just make sure your div is on top.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9vnske4/1/)

Comment: The only issue is that this method is slightly obtrusive and may obstruct website functionality (see: reddit).

Comment: What about if you wrap all of the contents in a div and then shift that div down, but keeping all positioning within that div consistent, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/w3hv1uz7/

Answer (score 0):

There is the bootsrap navbar: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Maybe solve your problem.